# Phaser 3: Why is my this.cameras.main.fadeOut effect not starting immediately?

Tags: phaser-framework

I am trying to create a fade out/fade in effect between two scenes, but for some reason the fade out effect doesn't start until after the player leaves the "portkey".

I am using an overlap check to see if the player is touching the goal and then I have a callback to a "touchGoal" function. Based on the [documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.ArcadePhysics.html#overlap__anchor), I would assume that is the correct way to do it, but maybe I am missing something?

Here is my overlap check:

```
this.physics.add.overlap(this.player, this.goal, this.touchGoal, false, this);
```

and this is the callback function:

```
touchGoal() {
    this.cameras.main.fadeOut(2000, 255, 255, 255, () => {
      this.cameras.main.on('camerafadeoutcomplete', () => {
        this.scene.start('scene2');
      }, this);
    });
  }
```

I also created a codepen so you can see it in action:
https://codepen.io/moorehannah/pen/bGbwOrO

Another thing that I am confused about is that when I run this code locally I am getting a black screen for a split second when I fade between the scenes. Does anyone know why that might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation isn't super clear about this, but the overlap callback method (which you setup correctly!) is triggered repeatedly while the two objects are overlapping. Your scene fade-out isn't starting until the player leaves the goal because as long as the player and goal are overlapping, your fade out keeps restarting at the beginning.

To avoid this behavior, all you need to do is add a boolean to the callback method to see if it's been triggered already. Then, each overlap will result in only 1 callback trigger.

Declare your boolean in the constructor:

```
constructor() {
  super('scene1');
  ...
  this.fadeTriggered = false;
}
```

And then wrap your `touchGoal()` contents in a boolean check:

```
touchGoal() {
  if (!this.fadeTriggered) {
    this.fadeTriggered = true;
    this.cameras.main.fadeOut(2000, 255, 255, 255, () => {
      this.cameras.main.on('camerafadeoutcomplete', () => {
        this.scene.start('scene2');
      }, this);
    });
  }
}
```

I'm not seeing the black screen between scenes, but looking at your codepen (very helpful, thanks for providing!) it could be because both Scene classes have separate `preload()` methods. If it's going to be a small game with a lot of reused assets, I'd recommend creating a load scene to preload all of your reused assets before triggering the Scene1 to start.

Comment: Ooooh that makes a lot of sense. I should have realized it would keep restarting the fade. Thank you so much @brae! I will also create a load scene and see if that fixes the black screen.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you, but I have a couple of other questions if you have time. 

Would you by any chance also know why the player slowly slides down when she is on the tree/ladder? I have set the gravity to 0 if the player is idle on the tree, but you will see that she slowly slides down 1px every second or so.

The other issue is that I can't get my "climb" animation to play when the "up" key is pressed down. If I switch the animation to happen when the "right" key is pressed down then it works. Do you have any ideas why that is?
https://codepen.io/moorehannah/pen/bGbwOrO

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why but when the player is idle on the tree, the velocity still looks to be minimal and that's what's causing the subtle slide down. If you change your `this.player.setVelocityY(-4);` to `-5` it seems to correct the issue.